# Updating query joining three tables to find specific records, need to update it to include all records from one table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Old question was closed and more information was requested so I've added some input/output screenshots here.

This seems like a simple thing to do conceptually, but I've tried updating the query and have had no luck so maybe someone can see something that I'm not seeing. In this excerpt I've changed the table names/aliases and removed a couple columns for brevity, but I have the following query:

```
SELECT t1.name, 
       t1.status, 
       t1.pid, 
       TIME(date_time) AS time, 
       t2.channel_name, 
       chattime, 
       email_sent, 
       sms_sent, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN notes = 'email' 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 END) AS email 
FROM       table1 t1 
RIGHT JOIN table3 t3 
        ON t1.pid = t3.pid 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
       ON t2.channel_name = t3.channel_name 
GROUP BY t3.channel_name, 
         t1.pid, 
         date 
ORDER BY t3.id DESC;
```

Essentially what I'm doing is pulling in all records from table3, and if there's a corresponding record in table2 the "chattime" column, which comes from t2, is also inserted into that record. Table1 contains some other information associated with these entries.

What I need to do now is change the query so I still get all these records but also get every single record from table2 regardless of whether or not there's a matching *channel_name* in table3 on which I can join the entries. I don't want duplicate entries, so my result set should basically be everything I currently have plus all the table2 records that haven't already been associated with an entry in table3.

I tried updating the joins and trying to add in a table2.* selector, but I've yet to find anything that does the trick. If anything about the question is unclear please feel free to let me know.

**EDIT**

As requested, I'll add some more information about the inputs and outputs. This query is used to input information into a PHP page with output like so:

[image: Report generated from query]

And here are a few records from each of the three tables involved. I've omitted names from this screenshot and the one above. The top is table1, middle is table2, and bottom is table3.

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

[image: Table 3]

And here is how the columns on the output page are laid out in terms of what comes from where:

Client: table1.name
PID: table1.pid
Date: table3.date_time
Practice email, number, areas, let us call you, form sent: t3.inquiry_notes (the database records each button click and the inquiry notes indicate what kind of click it was, hence why I had to group by table3.channel_name to get everything in one record on the output)
Chat: table2.chattime
Email sent: table2.email_sent
SMS sent: table2.sms_sent

Update with union query:

```
SELECT t1.name, 
    t1.chat_status, 
    t1.pid, 
    TIME(date_time) AS time, 
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date_time), '%a, %e %M %Y') AS date, 
    t2.channel_name, 
    chattime, 
    email_sent, 
    sms_sent, 
    sum(CASE WHEN inquiry_notes = 'email click' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS email, 
    sum(CASE WHEN inquiry_notes = 'phone click' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS phone, 
    sum(CASE WHEN inquiry_notes = 'practice area click' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS practice, 
    sum(CASE WHEN inquiry_notes = 'inquiry form click' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS form, 
    sum(CASE WHEN inquiry_notes NOT LIKE '%click%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS formsent 
    FROM 
        table1 t1 
            RIGHT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
            t2.channel_name, t3.id, t3.pid, t3.inquiry_notes, t3.channel_name, t3.date_time 
        FROM
            table3 t3
        LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.channel_name = t3.channel_name UNION SELECT 
          t2.channel_name, t3.id, t3.pid, t3.inquiry_notes, t3.channel_name, t3.date_time
        FROM
            table3 t3 
        RIGHT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.channel_name = t3.channel_name) t23 ON t1.pid = t23.pid 
    GROUP BY t3.channel_name, t1.pid, date 
    ORDER BY t3.id DESC
```

Comment: mysql doesn't support full outer join, so you have to simulate it. if you look for it you will find multiple solutions

Comment: I saw your comment on the old one and tried using a union but wasn't able to get it to work. I had to add some null columns to avoid the "unequal number of columns" error, but that threw off the columns in the output. I wasn't able to find a solution that preserved the proper output formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will give you a Version that will work, when the table 3 and tabl3 have no duplicate columns.

SELECT * is a bad option, but your images are bad to read.

Besides read for futre reference [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

```
SELECT 
    t1.name,
    t1.status,
    t1.pid,
    TIME(date_time) AS time,
    t2.channel_name,
    chattime,
    email_sent,
    sms_sent,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN notes = 'email' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS email
FROM
    table1 t1
        RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        table3 t3
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.channel_name = t3.channel_name UNION SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        table3 t3
    RIGHT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.channel_name = t3.channel_name) t23 ON t1.pid = t23.pid
GROUP BY t3.channel_name , t1.pid , date
ORDER BY t3.id DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll work from this and see where it gets me. I currently get a "duplicate column name 'channel_name'" error but maybe I wrote part of it incorrectly. Sorry about the images, I'll take a look at that link as well; it was the easiest way I could think of to try and convey what I need to do.

Comment: replace the SELECT * with SELECt t3.pid and so on with named columns, till the error doesn't occur and use that

Comment: I tried to do that as well and went back to getting the "used select statements have different number of columns" error no matter how I tried to even everything out with null columns. I'm getting the impression that I'm just completely in over my head with this.

Comment: you have to select in the left join and the right join of Course the **same** columns for union to work

Comment: I added the query I'm working with to the end of my original post now that I'm fiddling with it, I changed the * to select only the columns I need and I'm now back to getting the "duplicate column name" error after trying to specify which columns I'm getting.

I can understand why it's giving me this error since I did use the same column names to try and fix the previous uneven columns issue, so I'm guessing I may simply be selecting those at the wrong point in the query.

Thanks for your help thus far, I've been stuck on this for quite some time now.

Comment: it is very confusing you have a column date time and i can't see any of it in your images. make a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f62d5f5ac8e82415eb1bc354bf2e9d80 and add all tables and some data would alos be good.

Comment: I think it got cut off the end of the image, sorry -- the date_time column is in table3 and it's a current timestamp for whenever the entry is made. The output is split across the "date" and "time" columns in the first image. I'll look at dbfiddle and see if I can set something up.

Comment: I made a fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=69b5ffe8e6fbad0e0817cbbfe8a93180

I filled it in with a few records, let me know if you need more data.

Comment: i fixed the worst of it but your code produces no rows, but that can be because of the data. complex queires need a lot of knowledge, so i would recomend a course https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=08f8810497a0ea3d2c5366acf9b7d15e

Comment: Thanks, greatly appreciated. I see data on my end so everything is working with the exception of one type of entry, which is records in table2 that do not have a corresponding entry (e.g., channel_name to join on) in table3. I would need to get those records as well. I'm working on learning more about mySQL and these sorts of queries in general, a course would be helpful; most of what I'm doing now I'm learning on the job but I'd like to understand what's going on. I may not get a chance to check this page for a few hours so no worries about needing a reply quickly. Thanks again.

Comment: Full outer join should give you all records of table2 or 3 and where there is no record corresponding you get NULL. start by taking the union alone an see the results, After that you only join table1 and then you should see all results.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try tomorrow morning and see if the results are appearing correctly.

Comment: I've made a couple of changes this morning after comparing the result sets with and without the outermost join and I think it's now working correctly, can't thank you enough for your help. I'll leave the question open for the next day or so to see if any other issues arise but if everything looks good then I'll mark the answer as accepted. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm getting all the records to come in correctly, the only issue I'm currently seeing is that for all records in table2 where there's no corresponding table3 entry, the fields from table1 are null so there's no name or pid being displayed. It works perfectly for cases where there's a matching channel name in table2 and table3, but for some reason on the rest of the table2 records there's no information from table1. I've tried a couple of fixes but no luck yet, so I'll look into it tomorrow and see what I can find.

Comment: so i corrected an error in your supplied data and it works fine so far. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a9e5545bbeb38b2484f08bac11bb4a6

Comment: I added an entry into table2 and it's not in the main queyr output, maybe I made an error while adding the record? I also updated the pid value for the current third result and it still shows as null in the output, which is my current issue. All entries will have a pid, status (not displayed in output), and name from table1, so those output columns should always have values. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=50b1379d4e47fc2cbe406181743cf361 I also had to remove the MAX() around all the table1 values in my actual code, otherwise they were always null. Maybe that's related somehow.

Comment: i added the left and right join as separate queires so that you can see the result and as i said start from the union and add table1 and see what you need. that is normal for sql at least at the beginning

Comment: I'll go through the union query now and see if I need to add an additional join for table1 somewhere, maybe that's the reason I'm not getting the table1 data for those entries.

Comment: After playing with it for a while I've tried adding a couple of table1 joins to the union selects and I see the t1 columns correctly. When I update the main query using those joins it seems to be back to excluding the results that appear only in table2, which I've also checked with own code and data. Maybe I set up one of the new table1 joins incorrectly, it looks like the problem may be that t1 and t2 are never joined? The updated queries are in the fiddle.

Comment: I've been looking into this yesterday and today and my best guess for the problem above, where t2 entries without a t3 entry have no t1 data, is that there's no direct t1-t2 join so if there's no corresponding t3 record the name, status, and pid aren't recorded. I spent some time trying to update the inner query (the one with the union), adding some t1 fields and joining t1, but haven't had any luck. Am I on the right track with this line of thinking or could the issue be something else?